# Fatal Exception - java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

Tags: java, android, casting, fatal-error

I'm having an issue where I'm getting a fatal exception due to a class classcast exception. I've done a bit of research and found this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html

However it's my first time running into such an issue - and I'm not sure exactly how it can be resolved.

```
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.project.example.ssettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.setProgressImgView(UpdateActivity.java:365)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.project.example.ssettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onProgressUpdate(UpdateActivity.java:352)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.project.example.ssettings.UpdateActivity$NetworkTask.onProgressUpdate(UpdateActivity.java:1)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:432)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-19 15:41:48.711: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
    @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // Call function to update image view
            setProgressImgView(progress[0], progress[1], progress[2],
                    progress[3], progress[4]);
        }

        private void setProgressImgView(Integer imgViewId1, Integer imgViewId2,
                Integer imgViewId3, Integer imgViewId4, Integer imgViewId5) {
            // update image view with the updating dots
            // Reset view layout in case orientation while updating
            setContentView(R.layout.updating);
            mProgressImageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);
            mProgressImageview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);
            mProgressImageview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty3);
            mProgressImageview4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty4);
            mProgressImageview5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty5);
            mProgressImageview1.setImageResource(imgViewId1);
            mProgressImageview2.setImageResource(imgViewId2);
            mProgressImageview3.setImageResource(imgViewId3);
            mProgressImageview4.setImageResource(imgViewId4);
            mProgressImageview5.setImageResource(imgViewId5);

        }
```

Comment: Please post your layout file

Comment: you must be casting an imageview or imagebutton or something else to your text view. instead cast (TextView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two assumptions I made because your code is without a context:

1. It looks like your code is from an AsyncTask, right?
2. You are using the AsyncTask as an inner class, right? (because otherwise you shouldn't be able to call `setContentView()`)

I guess you are calling `setContentView()` already in your `onCreate()` method of the activity. There is no need to call it twice (and handling orientation changes inside an AsyncTask is kind of wrong).

You should get your 5 ImageViews as member variables and just use these variables inside your `setProgressImgView()` without calling `setContentView()` again.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that one of your `(ImageView)` castings tries to cast a `TextView` into an `ImageView`, which is wrong.

Both inherit from `android.view.View` (and therefore can both be casted into `View`), but one cannot be casted into the other.